# How do I check for unknown values in a string

Tags: java, servlets

```
if (thirdLastLine.matches("Tests run: 12,  Failures: 3")) {



        System.out.println("Found: " + thirdLastLine);

    } else {
        System.out.println("No conditionString In File");
    }
```

Writing the values in the if statement requires me writing a single if condition for every value which is a bad practice. I was wondering how I could do this without any values. something like: if (lines.contains("Tests run: '',  Failures: ''")) tried this but it doesn't work.. what can I do? thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for this.

For instance:

```
// your input String
String line = "Tests run: 12,  Failures: 3";
// Defines a pattern where "Failures: [any number of digits > 0]"
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Failures: [1-9]+[0-9]*");
// Defines a matcher for your pattern against that line
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
// iterates over matches and prints the outcome if any
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: Failures: 3
```

Comment: While that regex filters out 0 failures. It doesn't properly handle numbers with a 0, i.e. 10, 100 etc. EDIT: This has been fixed.

Comment: New problem: `[1-9]+[0-9]?` Doesn't work with multiple zeroes like in 100. Use `[1-9][0-9]*` instead.

Comment: @Willem thanks for that - I edited quite quickly and didn't notice :)

Comment: I have just tried this but it returns Failures: 3 which is right as its been already defined. if I make a new submission that contains 1 failure it still returns Failures: 3. I want to read the exact line from the text file with the values contained within it when it isn't predefined. thanks

Comment: @Buzz replace the `String line = "[some literal]";` declaration with your own lines.

Comment: @Mena I am a novice programmer so I am struggling. could this be simplified please?

Comment: @Buzz I can't see how this could be simpler. For each line you are testing against, apply a new `Matcher` from your `Pattern` to the line. Then invoke once or iterate the invocation of `find` and if the condition fulfills (`find()` returns `boolean`), take action.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
    if (lines.matches("Tests run: [0-9]+,  Failures: [0-9]+")) { 
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println("KO");
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
I replaced `*` for `+` in regular expression.

Comment: I have just tried this out using the contain method but it doesn't work as I cant access the matches method. thanks

Comment: I assumed `lines` was a `String`, right? On the other hand, `contains()` does no admit a Regular Expression, but a `CharSequence`. And `matches()` method applies to a `String`

Comment: yeah that makes sense. I have changed the variable 'lines' to 'thirdLastLine' which is more specific to the particular line in the file to be read from. I have tried your current code but it still doesn't work. It has to do with your pattern which I am not very good at

Answer (score 0):

if (thirdLastLine.matches("Tests run: ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]),  Failures: ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])")){
            System.out.println("Ok");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not Ok");
        }

This regex did the trick after taking ages. Thanks for your answers :)